# Gathering document fragments at rendring time using `pug`

Tags: node.js, email, pug

I use `pug` to generate HTML email messages from a template:

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title Hello #{name}
  body
    ...
```

The `title` is the *subject* of the email.

Currently, I extract the `title` text content by parsing the HTML document rendered by `pug`. But it doesn't seem to be a very efficient way of doing.

Is there some feature or *hook* available in `pug` to collect part of the document while rendering it? I considered [pug filters](https://pugjs.org/language/filters.html), but as far as I understand, those are not suitable since they are triggered at compile time. Not while rendering the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came to a solution using a mixin:

```
mixin collect(name)
  -
    // This is just an ugly hack to
    // capture the inner block rendered
    // text
    const savedHtml = pug_html;
    pug_html = "";
    if (block) block();
    const innerHtml = pug_html;
    self[name]=innerHtml;

    pug_html = savedHtml+innerHtml;

html
  head
    title
      +collect('title')
        | Hello #{self.name}
```

```
var pug = require("pug");

const compiledFunction = pug.compileFile('template.pug', {debug:true,self:true});
console.log(compiledFunction(out={
  name: 'Timothy',
}));
console.log(JSON.stringify(out));
```

Displaying:

```
<html><head><title>Hello Timothy</title></head></html>
{"name":"Timothy","title":"Hello Timothy"}
```

The code of the `collect()` mixin is not particularly pretty because [as far as I know it there is no elegant way to capture the `block()` output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44629101/how-to-access-the-content-of-a-block-from-javascript-in-a-pug-mixin). So I had to tackle into the internal undocumented `pug_html` variable.

Or is there a cleaner way to achieve that?